# Salesforce PHP Tookit - Temporary Error in Name Resolution

Tags: integration, php

I am using the PHP Toolkit to connect to my Salesforce organisation. Information on the tookit can be found here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit

However, I have been getting errors now and then while using my app. The error is written below:

```
SoapClient::__doRequest() [<a href='soapclient.--dorequest'>soapclient.--dorequest</a>]: 
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php on line 46
```

These errors do not occur all the time, they only pop up now and then. The app is still working (most of the time). In my testing, I have never received this message, however, when deployed to the server with multiple client apps that connect to it, this error does get logged a couple of times a day.

Granted, there are hundreds or thousands of actions taken in the app per day. Error messages pop up in the iOS interface that there are connection problems. I am unclear as to whether they are actual internet connection issues (as the app is being used on mobile devices in various public locations) or the above is the source of the connectivity error messages.

Googling the error, I understand that the main reasons for this are normally DNS issues. For other users of the PHP toolkit, is this failure in name resolution inevitable and will occur sometimes when connecting to the Salesforce servers? As this only occurs a few times a day, when compared to the vast number of interactions per day, the impact is minimal.

However, I am a little bit of a perfectionist and trying to figure out if there is any way to eliminate this completely. Is there a problem in my server configuration or is it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to intermediate internet connection on your server(where PHP is hosted). Due to flickering internet connection PHP is not able to connect to SFDC. If this is asynchronous execution then you should implement retry mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Do you know a page that explains the technical cause of the error 'temporary failure in name resolution'? 

I've found in other sites comments from others saying that this error happens when the server is unable to find the ip address of the domain due to DNS lookup problems. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I don't have any link  to support it right now.